# create query join hibernate which returns multiple objects

Tags: hibernate

I am currently doing the following:

```
 Query q = session.createQuery("select x,s.id from com.package.IdLookupHDO x JOIN com.package.SourceDataHDO s ON x.identifier = s.sourcePrimaryIdentifier");
        for (Object obj : q.list()){

        }
```

I think this join query will work without a problem. However I expected the query to give back object arrays in the list method because I have requested two things in my select (IdLookupHDO and id).
I have searched around and cannot find an answer but how can I retrieve both selected objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `on` if you have a corresponding association in your persistent classes.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select x,s.id from IdLookupHDO x join x.sourceAssociation s");
```

This query will return the `List<Object[]>`

```
List<Object[]> result = (List<Object[]>)q.list();

for (Object[] obj : result){
  // obj[0] is x
  // obj[1] is s.id
}
```